# Parsing in PHP with BibTex entries

Tags: php, regex, parsing, string-formatting, bibtex

I am developing a PHP application to build a database of BibTex entries that I gather from a website. The problem I am encountering is that when I download the contents of the webpage, I get this unwanted content (including white spaces on the beginning of the file):

```
            BibTeX bibliography toplas.bib






%%% -*-BibTeX-*-
%%% ====================================================================
%%%  BibTeX-file{
%%%     author-1        = &#34;Preston Briggs&#34;,
%%%     author-2        = &#34;Nelson H. F. Beebe&#34;,
%%%     version         = &#34;2.115&#34;,
%%%     date            = &#34;21 January 2015&#34;,
%%%     time            = &#34;07:15:05 MDT&#34;,
%%%     filename        = &#34;toplas.bib&#34;,
%%%     address-1       = &#34;Tera Computer Company
%%%                        2815 Eastlake East
%%%                        Seattle, WA 98102
%%%                        USA&#34;,
%%%     address-2       = &#34;University of Utah
%%%                        Department of Mathematics, 110 LCB
%%%                        155 S 1400 E RM 233
%%%                        Salt Lake City, UT 84112-0090
%%%                        USA&#34;,
%%%     telephone-1     = &#34;+1 206 325-0800&#34;,
%%%     telephone-2     = &#34;+1 801 581 5254&#34;,
%%%     FAX-2           = &#34;+1 801 581 4148&#34;,
%%%    
%%%     codetable       = &#34;ISO/ASCII&#34;,
%%%     keywords        = &#34;bibliography, BibTeX, ACM Transactions on
%%%                        Programming Languages and Systems, TOPLAS&#34;,
%%%     license         = &#34;public domain&#34;,
%%%     supported       = &#34;yes&#34;,
%%%     docstring       = &#34;This is a COMPLETE bibliography of the journal
%%%                        ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and
%%%                        Systems (CODEN ATPSDT, ISSN 0164-0925
%%%                        (print), 1558-4593 (electronic)), informally
%%%                        known as TOPLAS, covering volumes 1--21
%%%                        (1988--1999).
%%%
%%%                        The publisher maintains a World Wide Web site
%%%                        for this journal at
%%%
%%%                            
%%%                        At version 2.115, the year coverage looked
%%%                        like this:
%%%
%%%                             1979 (  20)    1992 (  22)    2005 (  33)
%%%                             1980 (  33)    1993 (  32)    2006 (  27)
%%%                             1981 (  28)    1994 (  66)    2007 (  45)
%%%                             1982 (  39)    1995 (  39)    2008 (  33)
%%%                             1983 (  36)    1996 (  29)    2009 (  23)
%%%                             1984 (  34)    1997 (  35)    2010 (  21)
%%%                             1985 (  34)    1998 (  34)    2011 (  21)
%%%                             1986 (  26)    1999 (  32)    2012 (  17)
%%%                             1987 (  27)    2000 (  28)    2013 (  14)
%%%                             1988 (  32)    2001 (  14)    2014 (  14)
%%%                             1989 (  30)    2002 (  21)    2015 (   5)
%%%                             1990 (  28)    2003 (  20)
%%%                             1991 (  30)    2004 (  28)
%%%
%%%                             Article:       1049
%%%                             TechReport:       1
%%%
%%%                             Total entries: 1050
%%%
%%%                        This bibliography was initially constructed
%%%                        by hand by the first author (PB) from
%%%                        various sources, and at its last release in
%%%                        February 1995, had 447 entries.
%%%
%%%                        It was further extended by the second
%%%                        author (NHFB) using bibliographies in
%%%                        NHFB's personal files, from the OCLC
%%%                        Contents1st database, from the IEEE INSPEC
%%%                        database, from the computer graphics
%%%                        bibliography archive at ftp.siggraph.org,
%%%                        and from the computer science bibliography
%%%                        collection on ftp.ira.uka.de in
%%%                        /pub/bibliography to which many people of
%%%                        have contributed.  The snapshot of this
%%%                        collection was taken on 5-May-1994, and it
%%%                        consists of 441 BibTeX files, 2,672,675
%%%                        lines, 205,289 entries, and 6,375
%%%                        &lt;at&gt;String{} abbreviations, occupying
%%%                        94.8MB of disk space.  This work updated 85
%%%                        existing entries and added 104 new entries,
%%%                        completing coverage to for all issues up to
%%%                        Volume 17, Number 5, September 1995.
%%%
%%%                        Numerous errors in the sources noted above
%%%                        have been corrected.  Spelling has been
%%%                        verified with the UNIX spell and GNU ispell
%%%                        programs using the exception dictionary
%%%                        stored in the companion file with extension
%%%                        .sok.
%%%
%%%                        The ACM maintains Web pages with journal
%%%                        tables of contents for 1985--1995 at
%%%                     That data hasenter code here
%%%                        been automatically converted to BibTeX
%%%                        form, corrected for spelling and page
%%%                        number errors, and merged into this file.
%%%
%%%                        ACM copyrights explicitly permit abstracting
%%%                        with credit, so article abstracts, keywords,
%%%                        and subject classifications have been
%%%                        included in this bibliography wherever
%%%                        available.  Article reviews have been
%%%                        omitted, until their copyright status has
%%%                        been clarified.
%%%
%%%                        bibsource keys in the bibliography entries
%%%                        below indicate the entry originally came
%%%                        from the computer science bibliography
%%%                        archive, even though it has likely since
%%%                        been corrected and updated.
%%%
%%%                        URL keys in the bibliography point to
%%%                        World Wide Web locations of additional
%%%                        information about the entry.
%%%
%%%                        BibTeX citation tags are uniformly chosen as
%%%                        name:year:abbrev, where name is the family
%%%                        name of the first author or editor, year is a
%%%                        4-digit number, and abbrev is a 3-letter
%%%                        condensation of important title
%%%                        words. Citation tags were automatically
%%%                        generated by software developed for the
%%%                        BibNet Project.
%%%
%%%                        In this bibliography, entries are sorted in
%%%                        publication order, using bibsort -byvolume.
%%%
%%%                        The checksum field above contains a CRC-16
%%%                        checksum as the first value, followed by the
%%%                        equivalent of the standard UNIX wc (word
%%%                        count) utility output of lines, words, and
%%%                        characters.  This is produced by Robert
%%%                        Solovay's checksum utility.&#34;,
%%%  }
%%% ====================================================================

@Preamble{
    &#34;\hyphenation{
        Fa-la-schi
        Her-men-e-gil-do
        Lu-ba-chev-sky
        Pu-ru-sho-tha-man
        Roe-ver
        Ros-en-krantz
        Ru-dolph
    }&#34; #
    &#34;\ifx \undefined \circled \def \circled #1{(#1)}\fi&#34; #
    &#34;\ifx \undefined \reg \def \reg {\circled{R}}\fi&#34;
}

%%% ====================================================================
%%% Acknowledgement abbreviations:

@String{ack-meo =  &#34;Melissa E. O'Neill,
                    School of Computing Science,
                    Simon Fraser University,
                    Burnaby, BC,
                    Canada V5A 1S6,


@String{ack-nhfb = &#34;Nelson H. F. Beebe,
                    University of Utah,
                    Department of Mathematics, 110 LCB,
                    155 S 1400 E RM 233,
                    Salt Lake City, UT 84112-0090, USA,
                    Tel: +1 801 581 5254,
                    FAX: +1 801 581 4148,


@String{ack-pb =    &#34;Preston Briggs,
                     Tera Computer Company,
                     2815 Eastlake East,
                     Seattle, WA 98102,
                     USA,
                     Tel: +1 206 325-0800,
                     e-mail: \path|preston@tera.com|&#34;}

%%% ====================================================================
%%% Journal abbreviations:

@String{j-TOPLAS                = &#34;ACM Transactions on Programming
                                  Languages and Systems&#34;}

%%% ====================================================================
%%% Bibliography entries:
```

---

So basically I need everything that is below the last line: " %%% Bibliography entries: " and get that content so I can parse it using my BibTex parser.

I would really appreciate if someone could give me an efficient way to achieve this.

Thanks